What is this usage of 連展開 here?

The characters are designers so that's the context.
What does "B倍ヨコの2連展開" mean?  "B倍" is paper format, while ヨコ is "horizontal/side by side"
so  "2 B倍 side by side" but I can't make sense of the last word. how is 展開 used here? "Spread"?

Does it make more sense as 2連・展開?

To be honest no? I'm not sure what 展開 is going for

B倍・ヨコ・2連 would look like this

The basic meaning of 展開 is "rollout", "deployment", or "distribution". "Spread" also works, but here it means disseminating information rather than unfolding paper. It's used somewhat like a suffix to form compounds:

グローバル展開 global rollout (strategy)
多メディア展開 multimedia expansion
集中展開 concentrated expansion; dominant strategy

Likewise, 2連展開 (literally "two-chain rollout") refers to the practice of using a set of two posters designed and displayed together as a single unit.
